# Enabling Hive Lineage

Tags: hive, bigdata, data-lineage

I thought Hive lineage was not available, but after some research I have found that it can be enable. Some of the things I found while searching was enabling its lineage via either Cloudera Manager or IBM Infosphere, which I am not interested in. Finally found a tag that was supposed to enable it:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.post.hooks</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.LineageLogger</value>
  </property>
```

The mentioned tag had to be written in the hive-site.xml file, and was supposed to write the lineage in the directory /var/log/hive/lineage. I said supposed because I haven't found anything in that directory, in fact, it wasn't even created.
I am currently using Hive-server 3.12

Comment: Did you enable it via Cloudera Manager: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cn_admcfg_impala_lineage_log.html

Comment: I don't have a Cloudera Manager. Anyways, Hive capability of enabling lineage should be independent of it, right?

Comment: It is independent.  When you enabled it and restarted were there any errors in the hive log?  can you post the relevant portions in your question?

Comment: There are no errors. I have tried to create a table from another to see if the lineage would be created (create table x as select * from y;) but no errors have appeared neither the lineage.

Comment: @PabloOchoa  my 2 cents, did you try to run the hive  or create directory manually  with admin user? may be it is suppressing since directory is not available ?

Comment: @Girish501 I have just tried creating the directory /var/log/hive/lineage as you have suggested. I entered beeline and created a table from another (create table x as select * from y;), but when I went back to the directory it was empty again. I have also tried adding the property "lineage_event_log_dir" to erase any possibility (although /var/log/hive/lineage is the default directory), but still got nothing.